# Null pointer exception with data

Tags: android

Im working on a small project and I followed a tutorial on how to make a BarChart on android. Now when I try to run the code I get a nullpointer exception on line 27 which is

```
    BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(),getDataSet());
    chart.setData(data);
    chart.setDescription("My Chart");
    chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
    chart.invalidate();
```

Now i get the error with the chart.setData(data), So i suppose something is wrong with the BarData data?

Edit:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart.setData(com.github.mikephil.charting.data.ChartData)' on a null object reference                                                                   at groep2.project4.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)

Line 27 is the chart.setData(data)

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BarChart chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

    BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(),getDataSet());
    chart.setData(data);
    chart.setDescription("My Chart");
    chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
    chart.invalidate();
}

private ArrayList<IBarDataSet> getDataSet() {
    ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = null;
    ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<>();
    BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(110.000f, 0); // Jan
    valueSet1.add(v1e1);
    BarEntry v1e2 = new BarEntry(40.000f, 1); // Feb
    valueSet1.add(v1e2);
    BarEntry v1e3 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 2); // Mar
    valueSet1.add(v1e3);
    BarEntry v1e4 = new BarEntry(30.000f, 3); // Apr
    valueSet1.add(v1e4);
    BarEntry v1e5 = new BarEntry(90.000f, 4); // May
    valueSet1.add(v1e5);
    BarEntry v1e6 = new BarEntry(100.000f, 5); // Jun
    valueSet1.add(v1e6);

    ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet2 = new ArrayList<>();
    BarEntry v2e1 = new BarEntry(150.000f, 0); // Jan
    valueSet2.add(v2e1);
    BarEntry v2e2 = new BarEntry(90.000f, 1); // Feb
    valueSet2.add(v2e2);
    BarEntry v2e3 = new BarEntry(120.000f, 2); // Mar
    valueSet2.add(v2e3);
    BarEntry v2e4 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 3); // Apr
    valueSet2.add(v2e4);
    BarEntry v2e5 = new BarEntry(20.000f, 4); // May
    valueSet2.add(v2e5);
    BarEntry v2e6 = new BarEntry(80.000f, 5); // Jun
    valueSet2.add(v2e6);

    BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Brand 1");
    barDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0));
    BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(valueSet2, "Brand 2");
    barDataSet2.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
    dataSets.add(barDataSet2);
    return dataSets;
}

private ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues() {
    ArrayList<String> xAxis = new ArrayList<>();
    xAxis.add("JAN");
    xAxis.add("FEB");
    xAxis.add("MAR");
    xAxis.add("APR");
    xAxis.add("MAY");
    xAxis.add("JUN");
    return xAxis;
}
```

}

Comment: Or a problem with chart ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: post your crash log.. what is the code on line 27?

Answer (score 0):

first try to print the data in Log , or print it in a toast message.may be `data` contains null value.

Comment: Yh it does say data contains null value.

Comment: `BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(),getDataSet());` check this line

Comment: now I get the constructor error that says: Cannot resolve constructor arraylist<ibardataset> and arraylist<string>, I switched them since that was the way they were in the beginning.

Comment: I think you have to make arraylist public and should declare and add values before calling them

Comment: I mean in onCreate method first add values to array list and use that